# Python OverflowError: math range error being raised differently in different runs

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, overflow, exponent

My program seems to be crashing almost arbitrarily.

My code includes these two lines:

```
z[i, j] = -math.exp(oneminusbeta[j, i])
weights[i,j] = math.exp(beta[j,i] + oneminusbeta[j,i])
```

I've run my whole code before on data that had 2 dimensions, it was `7341 x 648`. I had no issues at all running that code.

But now the data I'm using is about ten times as big. It's `71678 x 648`, and I'm getting this error:

```
OverflowError: math range error
```

And I'm not getting this on any specific point. I'm logging comments before every line of code so that I can see what's causing the crash, and it appears the crash is happening more often on the second line mentioned above (`weights[i,j] = math.exp(beta[j,i] + oneminusbeta[j,i])`).

The thing is, it crashes at different times.
At first, it crashed at `weights[30816, 42]`. Then at `weights[55399, 43]`. Then at `z[33715,45]`. But the data is the same in all 3 cases.

What could the problem be? Is this a memory related issue with python? I'm using `Numba` too, by the way.

### Edit

I forgot to mention, I've put thresholds so that what goes into the `exp()` function doesn't exceed what 709 or -708, so technically there shouldn't be an overflow.

Answer (score 2):

The result of your calculation cannot be represented on your computer. This probably means that `math.exp(...)` is greater than about 10<sup>308</sup>, or the argument passed to `math.exp()`  is greater than about 710.

Try printing the values of `beta[j,i]` and `oneminusbeta[j,i]` before each calculation.

In fact, you don't have to print comments before every line of code. Instead, try wrapping the calculations with a `try` block, like so:

```
try:
  weights[i,j] = math.exp(beta[j,i] + oneminusbeta[j,i])
except OverflowError:
  print "Calculation failed! j=%d i=%d beta=%f oneminusbeta=%f"%(j,i,beta[j,i],oneminusbeta[j,i])
  raise
```

Comment: The values aren't that big, when I try them individually on a separate python console, they don't cause a crash. Also, I've put thresholds on my values so that they don't exceed 10^308 or 708. I just tried the raise error like you suggested - but it says NotImplementedError: offset=742 opcode=0x79 opname=SETUP_EXCEPT

Comment: I don't know why the exception handling didn't work. But youc an go back to logging the values. What happens when you add `beta[j,i]` and `oneminusbeta[j,i]` to your logging?

Comment: Yes I tried that, but not much difference. It crashed before printing out that they were added, that was at [30816, 42]. Then, later, it did add and print out [30816, 42], but crashed elsewhere. I am printing out the values of beta and oneminusbeta, but they're really not that large. For eg. -11 or -6 (with about 9 to 13 decimal places).

Comment: Now I'm not even using numba, here's the follow up, it crashes on another line but again crashes at different points: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124464/floatingpointerror-overflow-encountered-in-double-scalars

Answer (score 1):

Your overflow is almost certainly a real overflow; one of your values is too large to fit in a Python `float` (meaning a C `double`).

---

So, why does it happen in different places each time?

Because you're using Numba.

Numba JIT-compiles your code. If it detects that there's no contention, it can reorder your code—or even, at least in theory, run it in parallel on multiple cores or on the GPU (although I think at present you only get GPU computation if you code it explicitly with numba.cuda).

At any rate, this means that the path through your code can be nondeterministic. If there's more than one place an overflow could happen, you can't predict which one will fail and trigger the exception.

---

At any rate, that doesn't really matter. If your calculations are overflowing, you have to fix that. And the fact that different ones overflow each time shouldn't make it *that* much harder to debug—especially given that it apparently *usually* happens in a single place, just not always.