# FloatingPointError: overflow encountered in double_scalars

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, overflow

I've set up numpy.seterr as follows:

```
np.seterr(invalid='raise', over ='raise', under='raise')
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
    c = beta[j,i] + oneminusbeta[j,i]
FloatingPointError: overflow encountered in double_scalars
```

I've checked what `beta[j,i]` and `oneminusbeta[j,i]` are at the point of crash, and these are their values:

```
beta: -131.340389182 
oneminusbeta: 0.0
```

Please note, this line of addition (`beta[j,i] + oneminusbeta[j,i]`) has run for thousands of lines in a loop (that performs image classification) before crashing here at this point.
How can I deal with this? Is it necessary to change the type of the numpy arrays?
This is how I've initialized them:

```
beta = np.empty([m,n])
oneminusbeta = np.empty([m,n])
```

Is it possible to cast the individual values before adding them up? Rather than changing the entire array declarations? Or is this even a serious issue? Would it be safe to simply turn off the numpy.seterr configuration and let the calculations go ahead without raising the error?

### Edit

Someone suggested below, and I suspected as well, that the values being added shouldn't cause an overflow. Then how can I find out where the overflow is really happening?

This is my code:

```
epthreshold = 709 
enthreshold = -708

f.write("weights["+str(i)+", " + str(j)+"] = math.exp(beta: " +str(beta[j,i])+ " + oneminusbeta: " + str(oneminusbeta[j,i])+")\n"  )
c = beta[j,i] + oneminusbeta[j,i]
weights[i,j] = math.exp(np.clip(c, enthreshold, epthreshold))
```

And when I check my log file, this is the line I get:

```
weights[5550, 13] = math.exp(beta: -131.340389182 + oneminusbeta: 0.0)
```

### Edit 2

Here's the rest of my code, where variables `n`,`m` and `H` have already been initialized to integer values:

```
import numba
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

weights = np.empty([n,m])
for curr_n in range(n):
    for curr_m in range(m):
        weights[curr_n,curr_m] = 1.0/(n)

beta = np.empty([m,n])
oneminusbeta = np.empty([m,n])
for curr_class in range(m):
    for curr_sample in range(n):
        beta[curr_class,curr_sample] = 1./m

epthreshold = 709 # positive exponential threshold
enthreshold = -708

for h in range(H):
    print "Boosting round %d ... " % h
    z = np.empty([n,m]) 
    for j in range(m):    # computing working responses and weights, Step 2(a)(i)
        for i in range(no_samples): 
            i_class =  y[i] #get the correct class for the current sample
            if h == 0:
                z[i,j] = (int(j==i_class) - beta[j,i])/((beta[j,i])*(1. - beta[j,i]))
                weights[i,j] = beta[j,i]*(1. - beta[j,i])
            else:
                if j == i_class:
                    z[i,j] = math.exp(np.clip(-beta[j,i],enthreshold, epthreshold))
                else:
                    z[i,j] = -math.exp(np.clip(oneminusbeta[j,i], enthreshold, epthreshold))                            

                f.write("weights["+str(i)+", " + str(j)+"] = math.exp(beta: " +str(beta[j,i])+ " + oneminusbeta: " + str(oneminusbeta[j,i])+")\n"  )
                c = beta[j,i] + oneminusbeta[j,i]
                weights[i,j] = math.exp(np.clip(c, enthreshold, epthreshold))


    g_h = np.zeros([1,1])
    j = 0
    # Calculating regression coefficients per class
    # building the parameters per j class
    for y1_w in zip(z.T, weights.T):
        y1, w = y1_w 
        temp_g = sm.WLS(y1, X, w).fit()  # Step 2(a)(ii)
        if np.allclose(g_h,0):
               g_h = temp_g.params
        else:
                g_h = np.c_[g_h, temp_g.params] 
        j = j + 1

    if np.allclose(g,0):
        g = g_h
    else:            
        g = g + g_h # Step(2)(a)(iii)

    # now set g(x), function coefficients according to new formula, step (2)(b)
    sum_g = g.sum(axis=1)
    for j in range(m): 
        diff = (g[:,j] - ((1./m) * sum_g))
        g[:,j] = ((m-1.)/m) * diff 
        g_per_round[h,:,j] = g[:,j]
    #Now computing beta, Step 2(c)...."
    Q = 0.
    e = 0.
    for j in range(m):
        # Calculating beta and oneminusbeta for class j
        aj = 0.0
        for i in range(no_samples):
            i_class = y[i]
            X1 = X[i].reshape(1, no_features)
            g1 = g[:,j].reshape(no_features, 1)
            gc =  g[:,i_class].reshape(no_features, 1)
            dot = 1. + float(np.dot(X1, g1)) - float(np.dot(X1,gc))
            aj = dot
            sum_e = 0.
            a_q = []
            a_q.append(0.)
            for j2 in range(m): # calculating sum of e's except for all j except where j=i_class
                if j2 != i_class: # g based on j2, not necessarily g1?
                    g2 = g[:,j2].reshape(no_features, 1)
                    dot1 = 1. + float(np.dot(X1, g2)) - float(np.dot(X1,gc))
                    e2 = math.exp(np.clip(dot1,enthreshold, epthreshold))
                    sum_e = sum_e + e2
                    a_q.append(dot1)

            if (int(j==i_class) == 1):
                a_q_arr = np.array(a_q)                        
                alpha = np.array(a_q_arr[1:])  
                Q = mylogsumexp(f,a_q_arr, 1, 0)
                sumalpha = mylogsumexp(f,alpha, 1, 0)
                beta[j,i] = -Q
                oneminusbeta[j,i] = sumalpha - Q
            else:
                alpha = a_q
                alpha = np.array(alpha[1:])
                a_q_arr = np.array(a_q)
                Q = mylogsumexp(f,a_q_arr, 0, aj)
                sumalpha = log(math.exp(np.clip(Q, enthreshold, epthreshold)) - math.exp(np.clip(aj, enthreshold, epthreshold)))

                beta[j,i] = aj - Q
                oneminusbeta[j,i] = sumalpha - Q
```

and the function `mylogsumexp` is:

```
def mylogsumexp(f, a, is_class, maxaj, axis=None, b=None):
    np.seterr(over="raise", under="raise", invalid="raise")
    threshold = -sys.float_info.max    
    maxthreshold = sys.float_info.max
    epthreshold = 709 # positive exponential threshold
    enthreshold = -708

    a = asarray(a)

    if axis is None:
        a = a.ravel()
    else:
        a = rollaxis(a, axis)

    if is_class == 1:
        a_max = a.max(axis=0)
    else:
        a_max = maxaj 

    #bnone = " none "
    if b is not None:
        a_max = maxaj
        b = asarray(b)
        if axis is None:
            b = b.ravel()
        else:
            b = rollaxis(b, axis)
        a = np.clip(a - a_max, enthreshold, epthreshold)
        midout = np.sum(np.exp(a), axis=0)
        midout = 1.0 + np.clip(midout - math.exp(a_max), threshold, maxthreshold)
        out = np.log(midout)

    else:
        a = np.clip(a - a_max, enthreshold, epthreshold)
        out = np.log(np.sum(np.exp(a)))

    out += a_max
    if out == float("inf"):
        out = maxthreshold
    if out == float("-inf"):
        out = threshold
    return out
```

Comment: This can't be correct. Adding those won't overflow. I suggest you make sure you're giving the correct numbers.

Comment: I've edited my question to add the code that outputs the values

Comment: What `dtype`s are these?

Comment: I didn't set a dtype. I just initialized them with np.empty

Comment: They still *have* a `dtype`, it'll just be default. Can you print it out? (`value.dtype`)

Comment: Also, what are `enthreshold` and `epthreshold`?

Comment: This is how I initialized them:    `epthreshold = 709` , `enthreshold = -708`. As for the dtypes - I've added a line to print them out, the code's still running... I'm just waiting a few minutes till it gets to that part. This is a long image classification algorithm.

Comment: I don't think it's going to help. I honestly can't see how this code is causing this.

Comment: Can you try initializing with `numpy.zeros` instead of `numpy.empty` and seeing if the same thing occurs? If it doesn't it's an initialization problem.

Comment: I'll do that and comment back here.

Comment: But if np.seterr brings up this line - it must be this line right? Or is there any other possible way of finding out?

Comment: It's really hard to tell without actually having a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: Alright, I'll work on MWE and post it here. It's just that it's really long...

Comment: I've edited the question to add the code. This still can't be a MWE - even if it were, it would run fine on your machine. It ran fine for me until I used a larger dataset, of about 700,000 datapoints, on which it's crashing. When I ran it with 30% of this data, there weren't any issues.

Comment: Does it crash with random data of similar magnitude?

Comment: dtype is float64 for both `beta` and  `oneminusbeta`.

Comment: This time it crashed on `weights[62546, 14] = math.exp(beta: -39.1555465659 + oneminusbeta: 0.0)` (different from the point it crashed above. I've changed the initialize to use np.zeros (instead of empty). This problem is actually a follow-up to this, where earlier I was using numba, and crashing on different points:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25820838/python-overflowerror-math-range-error-being-raised-differently-in-different-run  So apparently, whether I use numba or not, I'm crashing at different points when I use a lot of data. Is there a problem with just having too much data?

Comment: It's not crashing any more! I used a catch-except block. But when I tested the performance, the results were weird. Now I'm realizing that float64 addition isn't adding up somehow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314440/the-sum-of-float64-numbers-coming-out-weird-in-python